# WSL v1 - npm crashes at installing grpc

Tags: npm, grpc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL v.1 and I'm trying to start locally the [DataTurks](https://github.com/DataTurks/DataTurks/)' frontend bazaar app which is React based. So I basically type `npm install` but I run into an error when the `npm` reaches the library `grpc` and the error provided is:

```
path /home/kmartin62/DataTurks/bazaar/node_modules/.staging/grpc-2c7a1feb/node_modules/mkdirp
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/home/kmartin62/DataTurks/bazaar/node_modules/.staging/grpc-2c7a1feb/node_modules/mkdirp' -> '/home/kmartin62/DataTurks/bazaar/node_modules/.staging/mkdirp-97188a16'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/home/kmartin62/DataTurks/bazaar/node_modules/.staging/grpc-2c7a1feb/node_modules/mkdirp' -> '/home/kmartin62/DataTurks/bazaar/node_modules/.staging/mkdirp-97188a16'
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/home/kmartin62/DataTurks/bazaar/node_modules/.staging/grpc-2c7a1feb/node_modules/mkdirp' -> '/home/kmartin62/DataTurks/bazaar/node_modules/.staging/mkdirp-97188a16'
npm ERR!      errno: -13,
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!      path: '/home/kmartin62/DataTurks/bazaar/node_modules/.staging/grpc-2c7a1feb/node_modules/mkdirp',
npm ERR!      dest: '/home/kmartin62/DataTurks/bazaar/node_modules/.staging/mkdirp-97188a16' },
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename \'/home/kmartin62/DataTurks/bazaar/node_modules/.staging/grpc-2c7a1feb/node_modules/mkdirp\' -> \'/home/kmartin62/DataTurks/bazaar/node_modules/.staging/mkdirp-97188a16\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/kmartin62/DataTurks/bazaar/node_modules/.staging/grpc-2c7a1feb/node_modules/mkdirp',
npm ERR!   dest: '/home/kmartin62/DataTurks/bazaar/node_modules/.staging/mkdirp-97188a16',
npm ERR!   parent: '@firebase/firestore' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

I tried to install it as a super-user, `sudo` but the error keeps flashing. I even installed `grpc` with `-g` option ahead, for a global install, but when I run `npm install` after this it crashes again.

Has anyone experienced this or does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an instance of one of the oldest bugs in WSL v1, impacting many different npm packages: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/14. I also use WSL for development and I resolved the problem by switching to WSL v2.